# How I get maven to build a distribution?

Tags: maven

How can I coerce `maven` to produce a standalone jar with all dependencies present so that I can run it from a simple `java -jar ...` invocation?

This is my pom:

```
<project ...>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.11</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
    
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
           <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
              <mainClass>com.mkyong.hashing.App</mainClass>
           </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>copy</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>copy</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>

      <configuration>
        <artifactItems>
          <artifactItem>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <overWrite>false</overWrite>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
            <!--<destFileName>optional-new-name.jar</destFileName>-->
          </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
        <artifactItems>
          <artifactItem>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <overWrite>false</overWrite>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
            <!--<destFileName>optional-new-name.jar</destFileName>-->
          </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
        <artifactItems>
          <artifactItem>
             <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
             <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
             <version>2.9.0</version>
             <type>jar</type>
             <overWrite>false</overWrite>
             <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
             <!--<destFileName>optional-new-name.jar</destFileName>-->
           </artifactItem>
         </artifactItems>
         <artifactItems>
           <artifactItem>
             <groupId>junit</groupId>
             <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
             <version>4.12</version>
             <type>jar</type>
             <overWrite>false</overWrite>
             <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
             <!--<destFileName>optional-new-name.jar</destFileName>-->
           </artifactItem>
         </artifactItems>
       </configuration>
    
    <!--<executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>
                  ${project.build.directory}/lib
                </outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>-->
</plugin>
    
    
    
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactSet>
              <!--
                <excludes>
                  <exclude>classworlds:classworlds</exclude>
                  <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>
                  <exclude>jmock:*</exclude>
                  <exclude>*:xml-apis</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.apache.maven:lib:tests</exclude>
                  <exclude>log4j:log4j:jar:</exclude>
                </excludes>
              -->
              </artifactSet>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- <descriptor>src/assembly/dep.xml</descriptor>  -->
    
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.mkyong.hashing</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>create-archive</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

https://pasteb  in.com/xEeYGTtB

I am attempting to use `maven-dependency-plugin` and or `maven-shade-plugin` to put create a giant jar that can stand alone, running from only

```
java -jar giant-jar.jar
```

Comment: Probably what you are looking is a fat jar, see https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/

Comment: Please don't post your complete code but only the relevant part. And your question should show the effort you've tried to find a solution for your problem.

Comment: Sorry I didnt want to leave anything out and I really dont know what I'm doing anyway.

Comment: To get all files into a zip file the best option is to go via maven-assembly-plugin....

Answer (score 0):

Create a XML file in `src/main/assembly`. Let's call it `zip.xml`.

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>zip</id>
    <includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>

    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <files>
        <file>
            <source> ${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</source>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </file>
    </files>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}:jar:*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Refer to the created XML file in `pom.xml` using the Maven Assembly plugin. Change your assembly plugin code to following in `pom.xml`.

```
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            <descriptors>
               <descriptor>src/main/assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Finally, build the code using `mvn clean install` and if the build got successful, you will see the zip file in the `target` directory.